# Can I run Scrapy on Windows with Python 3?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, twisted, pywin32

Seems like Scrapy 1.1.0rc3 isn't working on Windows with Python 3.

When I run `scrapy crawl dmoz` command specified on [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) I get following exception:

```
D:\Copy From 2\Python Project\ZhihuPlan\tutorial\tutorial>scrapy crawl dmoz
2016-04-26 14:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0rc3 started (bot: tutorial)
2016-04-26 14:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders'}
2016-04-26 14:40:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-04-26 14:40:36 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)  
File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 163, in crawl return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)  
File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 167, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)  
File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine  
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)  
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)  
  File "d:\anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import

 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 23, in <module>
    from scrapy.xlib.tx import ResponseFailed
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\xlib\tx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.web import client
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, SSL4ClientEndpoint
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 34, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'
2016-04-26 14:40:36 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Is there any way to fix this error? Can I run Scrapy on Windows with Python 3?

Comment: Please check the installation notes here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes

Comment: I checked it many times but unuseful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot run Scrapy on Windows with Python 3.

Scrapy currently does not support Python 3 on Windows. See release notes here (scroll to limitations section) https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/02/04/python-3-support-with-scrapy-1-1rc1/ we're working on fixing this.

In the meantime you can try using different or different Python version.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy now works for on Windows 10 with Python 3. I tried it just now through conda prompt.

First, open conda and activate the environment to which you added scrapy.

```
conda activate <your environment>
```

Then run scrapy

```
scrapy runspider <path.to.file.py>
```

...and scrapy should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrapy runspider file_name.py -O file_name.csv` to save in .csv

Answer (score -1):

Scrapy works on the system Windows together Python 3.

Once you’ve installed Anaconda or Miniconda, install Scrapy with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy

scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Find the installation process here:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/intro/install.html